# Linking data validation drop-down

Tags: drop-down-menu, filter, excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 2 worksheets;

DATA

```
Client|Contract|Active
C1    |W100    |1
C1    |W101    |1
C1    |W102    |0
C2    |W103    |0
C3    |W104    |1
...
```

INVOICES

```
Client|Contract|Payment|...
C1    |W100    |10
C1    |W100    |10
C1    |W100    |100
C2    |W103    |5
...
```

What I want to do is;

1. Have a dropdown list in the Client column on the INVOICES worksheet which only displays those Clients who have an active contract as defined on the DATA worksheet
2. Have a dropdown list in the Contract column on the INVOICES worksheet which only displays the active contracts for the selected client

So for instance, to populate the next row on the INVOICES worksheet I would only see C1 & C3 in the dropdown list in the Client column. Assuming I select C3, then I will only see W104 in the dropdown in the Contract column.

Both sheets are set up as tables in Excel 2010.

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

You can give a `table as the source of drop down` in your excel.

[Try this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/13/dynamic-data-validation-excel/)

Comment: Thats right Nitesh, however I want the options in the drop down to be filtered to only those that are active.